# How does one implement drag-and-drop using Elm 0.17?

Tags: drag-and-drop, elm

elm-drag package does not work since Elm version 0.17.
Author mentioned it had no sense since when.

https://github.com/jvoigtlaender/elm-drag/issues/2

And pointed to the:
http://elm-lang.org/examples/drag

But it only has drag not drop.

The first thing I thought about is to catch onMouseUp in the drop target. And when do some on-drop actions if the drag event is somehow reflected at the model.

But I am not sure it is a right way.
What is the proper way to implement the drop at Elm 0.17?

Comment: In the [example you linked](http://elm-lang.org/examples/drag), the drop is effectively a call to `update` with the `DragEnd` Msg, triggered by the `Mouse.ups` subscription. The position of the drop is available at that time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I went through example again and again and now I realize more.
Do I need to compare the position available at DragEnd with all the drop targets?
Also, I need "helper" (as it named at jquery-draggable). So original drag source should keep on it's place and dynamically created element should be dragged.
Looks like it is way too hard for me newbie to implement it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that it is not sufficient to check a `drop target` for a `mouseover` event, but rather check if it intersects the `drag target`. I think that the [bounding-box](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/folkertdev/elm-bounding-box/latest) package could be useful.

Also, there are a couple of examples online which are somehow related to drag-and-drop (although not having arbitrary `drop targets`). Maybe they help:

- [Draggble Tabs](https://github.com/thebritican/elm-draggable-tabs)
- [Sortable List](https://github.com/zaboco/elm-draggable-examples/blob/master/src/SortableList.elm), using the [elm-draggable](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/zaboco/elm-draggable/latest) package. (*disclaimer: I'm the author*)